# UITableView.automaticDimension Not working tableView detailTextLabel

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am implementing `UITableViewController` Programmatically (No Storyboards!).

I tried many possible ways to implement automatic resizing of TableViewCell's `detailTextLabel` but none is working. I don't know what I am missing or whether it's a bug! Here's what I tried:

```
//Class - tableViewContoller
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setUpTableView()
}


func setUpTableView() {
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    tableView.separatorColor = UIColor(red: 240.0/255.0, green: 240.0/255.0, blue: 240.0/255.0, alpha: 0.8)
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 0.0)
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension //Tried 44 -> Not working either
    tableView.reloadData()
}
//cellForRowAt IndexPath
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId)
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.value1, reuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }
    cell?.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell?.detailTextLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    cell?.selectionStyle = .none
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        cell?.textLabel?.text = "Case 1"
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = caseDetails?.details
    case 1:
        cell?.textLabel?.text = "Case 2"
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = caseDetails?.bio
    default:break
    }
    return cell!
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

I have 2-3 cells where detailTextLabel may have multiple lines.
Please let me know what's that I'm missing here. What I figured after reading on the Internet is **to add custom constraints**, but I don't think that'll work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add constraints for that `cell?.detailTextLabel`

**cellForRowAt**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId)
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.value1, reuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }
    cell?.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell?.detailTextLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    cell?.selectionStyle = .none

    cell?.detailTextLabel?.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
    // ALLOW MANUAL CONSTRAINTS
    cell?.detailTextLabel?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    // TOP +15, BOTTOM -15, RIGHT -15
    cell?.detailTextLabel?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (cell?.contentView.topAnchor)!, constant: 15).isActive = true
    cell?.detailTextLabel?.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (cell?.contentView.bottomAnchor)!, constant: -15).isActive = true
    cell?.detailTextLabel?.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (cell?.contentView.rightAnchor)!, constant: -10).isActive = true

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        cell?.textLabel?.text = "Case 1"
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = "hi\nhello\nwelcome\nhow are you"
    case 1:
        cell?.textLabel?.text = "Case 2"
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = "caseDetails?.bio\n\n\n123456"
    default:break
    }
    return cell!
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! @McDonal_11 It worked like a charm, in one go. Edit - Just needed to add detailTextLabel-leftAnchor constraint from textLabel-rightAnchor.

Answer (score 0):

Should work if you set your estimated row height to an actual value.  You can't have both set to `.automaticDimension`.

Comment: I mentioned in the comment already, that's not working either!