# iOS - How can I implement iPhone Storage list(not custom cell)?

Tags: ios, uitableview

The iPhone Storage list shows as below:
[image: iPhone Storage list]
I want to implement this effect by Apple Native API instead of custom cell. I guess the UITableViewCellStyle is UITableViewCellStyleValue1, but how to do with the textLabel(two lines and different fonts)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You will need to make your own `UITableViewCell` subclass

Comment: You will get some idea with this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53581758/uitableview-automaticdimension-not-working-tableview-detailtextlabel/53582244#53582244

Comment: You have to give constraints prog, then u ll get this design, else, try with Attributed text for textLabel, it may allow multiple fonts for single label.